# Не работает ни один эмулятор консоли на windows

Tags: windows, консоль, windows-10, conemu

Всегда работал c ConEmu, но вдруг он перестал включаться.
После запуска сразу же выключается, перепробовал кучу других - тоже самое!

Не смог найти причину этому, сохранил все свои файлы в облако и пошел переустанавливать винду. После переустановки ConEmu заработал - я счастлив. Поработал, выключил комп, а на следующий день беда вернулась...

Что делать? Куда копать?

Comment: Обновления приехали?

Comment: Винда последней версии.

Comment: Я про то, что "на чистой винде работает, но потом приехали обновы и всё поломалось, да?"